# Android power button and webview or possibly activity lifecycle

Tags: android, android-activity, webview, android-lifecycle

I have issue with activity lifecycle with webview and power button.

I am loading javascript page with a game inside webview and I am preserving the webview in Application context, so it survives Activity destruction. I know I should't save the view like this but I have very specific scenario where it is the only solution. It is working fine when switching between apps (even with the "dont keep activities" debug flag) but when I do this scenario:

1. run activity with webview
2. once the game loads into webview press power button to turn off the screen
3. turn the screen back on
4. unlock the screen (by swiping up)
5. activity will load, but webview is not loaded, its just black screen

I tried printing out all activity lifecycle methods and its identical in both cases. What is the difference between those 2 scenarios?

Code app context:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    private WebView mWebView;

    //getter, setter ...
    //preserving webview in app context
}
```

Code activity:

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initWebView();
}

private void initWebView() {
    MyApp app = (MyApp) getApplication();
    mWebView = app.getWebView();
    if (!app.isWebViewInitialized()) {
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mWebView.requestFocus();
        mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavascriptInterface(this), "JSInterface");
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://js-game-url.com");
        mWebView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        app.setWebViewInitialized(true);
    } else {
        try {
            ((ViewGroup) mWebView.getParent()).removeView(mWebView);
            //todo remake the try catch
        } catch(NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println("Null");    //todo remove try catch
        }
    }


    webviewPlaceholder = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlayout2);
    webviewPlaceholder.addView(mWebView);
}

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    webviewPlaceholder.removeView(mWebView);
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initWebView();
}

protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    webviewPlaceholder.removeView(mWebView);
}
```

I am definitely missing something simple, but I cant find the solution.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my other answer.  After trying to understand what you're trying to do, I think it's impossible.  WebView as not designed to act like a full web browser by saving a persistent state for as long as you like (not even saveState and restoreState method will do what you want..  If you really need to save state, you'll have to build a javascript bridge between the WebView content and the app, and make sure it can save and restore whatever you need.

Comment: It is working fine, you can kill the activity and webview is properly stored with game progress and loaded back on once activity is created again. Problem is that there is probably some difference in lifecycle of activity when you use power button to turn off the screen versus switching between 2 opened activities.

Comment: If the JS hasn't loaded yet, when you turn off the screen, your work will most probably be halted, as you don't have a wake-lock for the CPU. What happens if you load the game completely and then turn off the screen after everything has loaded?

Comment: @Darwind in both cases the webview doesn't load but I think I know where the problem is. Its not the activity lifecycle but the javascript or the game lifecycle. Because the game pause itself when the window lose focus and I think the js fire different events in those 2 cases, I have to test it on some simple example.

Comment: Yes, I was right - the webview didnt get focus in my scenario: mWebView.requestFocus(); fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't problem with activity lifecycle but wit webview javascript lifecycle. The webview didn't get focus, when the activity got recreated after turning screen back on. This fixed it:

```
mWebView.requestFocus();
```